# Return index position from array of anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why these anonymous functions are returning the last value of my loop iterator as opposed to the iterator's current value when it is set.  I thought that values are exempt from pass by reference, but it looks like these return values are pointers to the original i?

```
function myFunctions(n) {

  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
    list.push(function(){
        return i;
    });    
  }
  return list;
}

var res = [];

myFunctions(4).map(function(el){
    res.push(el());
});

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = res.join(',');
document.body.appendChild(p);

//expected result: 0,1,2,3
```

Reading material: 
[Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZP2hM/

Comment: I think at the time you call any of the functions the value of the variable `i` its 4.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was a closure issue, I didn't find the answers above.

Answer (score -1):

this is a typical mistake people do using closures.
Here is a fix:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    var tmp = i;  
    list.push(function(){
        return tmp;
    });    
  }
```

This happens because all functions in list array are bound to current i value. When your cycle finishes i = n-1; That is why you get n-1 for all array elements. This is resolved by temporary variable which is unique for each list element.

Comment: If you run the code you will notice that this does not fix the problem. You just gave `i` a different name. All functions have a reference to the same `tmp` variable.

Comment: yes, this is not correct.  I think the suggested answer above properly describes how to wrap this in a closure and capture the value.